# Passing the default value of props to data in @Component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-class-components, vue-property-decorator

Having the code, I am getting `State: undefined` and clicking the toggle button does nothing.
How to get the default value from @Prop to some data correctly using @Component?

```
<script lang="ts">
import {
  Component,
  Prop,
  Vue,
} from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
    @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: true })
    expanded!: boolean;
    
    isExpanded = this.expanded;
    // if its isExpanded = true; then toggling works.
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="greetings">
    State: {{ isExpanded }}
    <br />
    <button @click="isExpanded = !isExpanded">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mutate the prop.  Instead send a message to the parent, and let the parent mutate it.

```html
<button @click="$emit('update:expanded', !expanded)">Toggle</button>
```

```html
<hello-world :expanded='theValue' @update:expanded='theValue=$event' />
```

Comment: I am not mutating, its isExpanded is a data variable.